# Help choosing statistical test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, likert

I need help deciding which statistical analysis I should run.
I am examining individuals with or without a chronic illness and if they differ on 2 questionnaires (1 is health literacy and the other is self-efficacy). The health literacy measure is a 4-point Likert scale, and the self-efficacy measure is a 10-point Likert scale. Does anyone need more information to help me with this?
Thank you very much in advance for responses!

Comment: You have not indicated scores and  sample-sizes.. what about scoring for two Likert Scales. Please state your objectives and analysy

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because while the OP asked if more information was needed, they did not answer a request for such information.